# libGDX reverse actor eventHandling

Tags: java, libgdx, event-handling, scene2d

I'm trying to create an universalish tab widget in libGDX. It contains a button bar and a pane bar and a pane view.

Lets assume the tabwidget is as big as the screen, and we have 3 tabs. The buttonbar takes up the top part of the screen, and the panes are in the bottom part. The paneView is a WidgetGroup for event handling, it is as big as the tabwidget minus the buttonBar.

[image: tabwidget]

Everything works just fine until I add an a scrollpane as a tab widget. Since this scrollPane calls:

```
event.stop();
```

the subsequent events are not called.

Since events "bubble" up through actors, the lowest level actor is handled first calling the event handlers of its parents and siblings upwards. This means the scrollpane is always handled before the tabwidget.

Is there a way to intert the order of the input listeners? Have the tab input be handled first and then the scrollpane input? Or will I have to reimplement the scrollpane handlers to get around this issue?

Comment: why do you use `event.stop()` - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: this is what the libGDX's own scrollPane does when handling scrolling. It's not in my own code.

Comment: ok I guess I see - so the scrollPane **overlaps** widget Group that you also want to "scroll" but since the event is "stopped" on scrollPane the scrollPane is scrolling and not the Group? **To sum up** - you want to be able to move whole Group horizontally and the Group's element vertically for example?

Comment: That is correct. Then I can decide to stop the handling of the scrollPane if the tabPane is being moved by just calling cancel on the scrollpane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the way you want to implement this is rather impossible - how actors would know if the **fling gesture** you are performing is addressed to which?

The resolution that comes to my mind is to

- Create new stage being input processor (if it will be second inputProcessor you will need [InputMultiplexer](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputMultiplexer.html) )
- Implement [GestureDetector](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/input/GestureDetector.html) and then detect horizontal swipes and react with moving group - [read this tutorial to get more information](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/input/GestureDetector.html)

In my opinion it is generally not good idea to modify libgdx sources but of course you can do it (by downloading LibGDX from Github and import it as project you will have access to all sources) although in this case it is definitely unnecessary.

Comment: I am calculating the flings myself, because I didn't like the gestureDetector. I had this working with an input processor in stead of an actor listener, but that way I cannot create a universally usable tab widget. Perhaps having a new stage inside of the tabwidget could be a solution (not sure how multiple will work together, and how the order is determined, I will test this).

I would not change libGDX source, just extend MyScrollPane with ScrollPane and reimplement the method that registers the capture/input listeners

Comment: I ended up adding a new stage for the interior of the widget and not adding it as a processor, but just calling the touch functions in the onTouch methods of my widget's listener. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!